# Java regular expressions with negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm facing some trouble writing a regular expression in Java to parse information from a logfile.

I have a String where the structure "timeinstant: some strings with any character" is repeated   from 1 to N times.

timeinstant has the format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss:MMMMMM" (M being microseconds).

What I'm trying to do is to find the microseconds of last timeinstant contained in an incoming string.

For example, with the string

```
] 2012/04/02 16:28:51:861819: abcdefg : lwersdgsdg remote=xx.xxx.xx.xxx:yyy3f] accepted and identified as: John 2012/04/02 16:28:51:862987: pump: Received data on connection {John} [
```

I'd like  `m.find()` to point to `"987: pump..."`. In order to get this, I'm using a regex with lookahead:

`"(\\d{3}:)(?!\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{6})"`

But right now `m.find()` is pointing to `819` (contained in `2012/04/02 16:28:51:861819`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is very near to the one you need.

In your negative lookhead, you just forgot that different timestamps are separated by several characters. So you have to add `.+` or `.*` in your lookahead to specify that.

Here is the regex you need:

```
"(\\d{3}):(?!.+\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{6})"
```

In your example, it will give you the "987" you are looking for.

Comment: That's it. I added .* at the begining and end of the lookahead.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the last occurrence of three digits followed by a colon, wouldn't `.*(\d{3}:)` work?

Comment: No, for some reason I get the first occurrence of thredigits followed by ":"

Comment: `".*(\\d{3}):"` should capture `987` not `819`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

`(\\d{3}: \\w+)`

and then use find.next() until there isn't any next?